# How to style mui-rte CodeBlock

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, rich-text-editor

By default the CodeBlock is styled with a white-ish background and black-ish color. This works fine with a "light" palette but is unreadable with a "dark" palette because with a "dark" palette the background stays white while the color also becomes to white. I can apply a theme based on palette but can't figure out how to style the CodeBlock. I would like to do something like the following:

```
const darkTheme = createMuiTheme()

Object.assign(darkTheme, {
   overrides: {
      CodeBlock: {
         root: {
            backgroundColor: '#37474F',
            color: '#fff',
         },
      },
   ....
 })
  ....    

    const MyEditor = (props: IProps) => {
       return (
                <MuiThemeProvider theme={getTheme(props.brightness)}>
                   <MUIRichTextEditor defaultValue="" label="Type something here..." onSave={save} inlineToolbar={true} />
                </MuiThemeProvider>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/niuware/mui-rte), you can use `inlineStyle` to set the background color.

Example:

```
import MUIRichTextEditor from 'mui-rte'
import InvertColorsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/InvertColors'

<MUIRichTextEditor 
    controls={["my-style"]}
    customControls={[
        {
            name: "my-style",
            icon: <InvertColorsIcon />,
            type: "inline",
            inlineStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "black",
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    ]}
/>
```

Another option according to the docs:

```
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import MUIRichTextEditor from 'mui-rte'

const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme()

Object.assign(defaultTheme, {
    overrides: {
        MUIRichTextEditor: {
            root: {
                marginTop: 20,
                width: "80%"
            },
            editor: {
                borderBottom: "1px solid gray" 
            }
        }
    }
})

<MuiThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
    <MUIRichTextEditor 
        label="Type something here..."
    />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: This code will place a MuiIconButton in the toolbar that will toggle an inline style. I tested this and it works to toggle the in-line style (it works like the "highlighter" button) but does not style the CodeBlock

Comment: Check the answer again. I updated it with another example provided by the docs. I believe the issue is that you named the override `CodeBlock` instead of `MuiRichTextEditor`

Comment: This is the code example I started with. Using this idea I have been able to style several classes. Everything looks great and works properly based on the users selected brightness except the CodeBlock. The CodeBlock still eludes me.

Comment: Perhaps try using a different class than `root`. I'm not sure exactly which class refers to the CodeBlock, but you can view the different classes here - https://github.com/niuware/mui-rte/blob/master/src/MUIRichTextEditor.tsx#L111. Perhaps defining the CSS in the `editorContainer` class is the answer?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element using something like Chrome DevTools to see exactly what class is responsible for styling the background color of the CodeBlock?

Comment: .CodeBlock-root-478 {
    padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
} controls the background color. This is the guy I would like to target. But I am missing something.

Comment: It may be a limitation of mui-rte. Here is where that CSS is defined, and it doesn't seem like it can be overriden - https://github.com/niuware/mui-rte/blob/52c77236f42ad11d5abfab6d9f871b04d202afd7/src/components/CodeBlock.tsx

Answer (score 3):

Jakes answer is correct I think. There does not seem to be a way to style the '.CodeBlock' specifically.  I opened a ticket with mui-rte. I was able to code a fairly nice looking dark mode editor with a readable '.CodeBlock' as follows:

```js
const darkTheme = createMuiTheme()

Object.assign(darkTheme, {
   overrides: {
      MuiIconButton: {
         root: {
            color: '#fff',
         },
      },
      MUIRichTextEditor: {
         root: {
            '& pre': {
               color: '#212121',
            },
         },
         editor: {
            padding: '20px',
            height: '200px',
            maxHeight: '200px',
            overflow: 'auto',
         },
         placeHolder: {
            paddingLeft: 20,
            width: 'inherit',
            position: 'static',
         },
         anchorLink: {
            color: '#FFEB3B',
            textDecoration: 'underline',
         },
      },
   },
})

interface IProps {
   brightness: string
}

const MyEditor = (props: IProps) => {
   return (
      <div>
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{ overflow: 'auto' }}>
            <TextField>ff</TextField>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={getTheme(props.brightness)}>
               <MUIRichTextEditor defaultValue="" label="Type something here..." onSave={save} inlineToolbar={true} />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
            <br />
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
               submit
            </Button>
         </form>
      </div>
   )
}

export default MyEditor
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit allows you to do a bit more with the customization, like auto-sizing the block of code, adjusting the line-height, for example:

```
overrides: {
  MUIRichTextEditor: {
    root: {
      '& div[class^="CodeBlock"]': {
        'background-color': theme.palette.background.paper,
        color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
        'display': 'inline-block',
        'line-height': 0
      }
    }, ...
```

However, Jake's code might also work like the following:

```
import MUIRichTextEditor from 'mui-rte';
import CodeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Code';

<MUIRichTextEditor 
  controls={["my-codeblock"]}
  customControls={[
    {
      name: "my-codeblock",
      icon: <CodeIcon />,
      type: "inline",
      inlineStyle: {
        bgcolor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
        'display': 'inline-block',
        'line-height': 0
        }
      }
  ]}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to change the color of the text if the editor is disabled.
This worked for me:

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        editorReadonly: {
            color: MBTheme.palette.grey[500],
        },
    })
    );

function TaskFormFields(props: EditTaskProps) {
    const translate = useTranslation();
    const intl = useIntl();

    const classes = useStyles();
           .
           .
           .


 return (
            <MUIRichTextEditor
                classes={{ editorReadOnly: classes.editorReadonly }}
                ref={rteRef as unknown as React.Ref<TMUIRichTextEditorRef>}
                readOnly={props.readonly}
                defaultValue={task.content ? ensureRichtText(task.content ?? '') : ''}
                label={props.readonly ? '' : translate('task_content')}
                onBlur={() => rteRef.current?.save()}
                onSave={(data: string) =>
                    task.content !== data && props.onChange && props.onChange({ ...task, content: data })
                }
            />)
```

Mui5,
React17,
Typescript